# Converting adb shell date returned value to Date Object in Java

Tags: java, android

adb shell date
returned 
Tue Feb 14 22:32:02 IST 2017

I am trying to converting the "Tue Feb 14 22:32:02 IST 2017" to Date object in java. Can you please help in giving the sample snippet in Java to do the same.
I tried with SimpleDateFormat to parse this string, but somehow getting parse exception.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
Date d = formatter.parse(dateStart);
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"); worked in conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting pattern must match the data. Yours is not a match.

- Remove the comma from your formatting pattern. Your data has no comma.
- Move the year symbol to the correct location.
- Add a time zone symbol for the `IST`.

---

Please search Stack Overflow before posting. There are hundreds of examples you could have drawn from to solve your problem.